# Implementing QuickSort on ArrayList of Object with a Queue Implementation

Tags: java, object, arraylist, queue, quicksort

First question: would there ever be a time in real life that one would need to sort a queue? I'm finding this assignment hard to apply to the real world.

Second, I need to QuickSort an ArrayList Queue. I'm trying to handle this error message and I'm not quite sure how to fix it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class com.company.Person (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.company.Person is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.company.QuickSort.quickSortAge(QuickSort.java:43)
    at com.company.Main.sort(Main.java:41)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:63)
```

Here is the relevant code:

Queue Interface:

```
package com.company;
public interface QueueInterface<T>{
     public void enqueue(T newEntry) throws Exception;
     public T dequeue();
     public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Queue Class:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Queue<T> implements QueueInterface<T>{
    private List<T> data;
    private int size;

    public Queue(){
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public void enqueue(T item) throws Exception {
        data.add(item);
        size++;
    }
    @Override
    public T getFront() {
        if(isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return data.get(0);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public T dequeue() {
        if(isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return data.remove(0);
        }
    }
    public int size(){
        return size;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size == 0;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String result = "(" + data.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
            result += ")\n(" + data.get(i);
        }
        result += ")";
        return result;
     }
     public T get(int index){
        return data.get(index);
     }
}
```

QuickSort Class:

```
package com.company;
public class QuickSort {
    private int compareLastName(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
    }
    private int compareAge(Person p1, Person p2){
        return p1.getAge() - (p2.getAge());
    }
    protected Queue quickSortLastName(Queue<Person> queue) throws Exception {
        if (queue.size() <= 1) {
            return queue;
        }
        Queue lesser = new Queue();
        Queue greater = new Queue();
        int pivot = queue.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (compareLastName(queue.get(i), queue.get(pivot)) < 0){
                lesser.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
            else {
                greater.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
        }
        lesser = quickSortLastName(lesser);
        greater = quickSortLastName(greater);

        lesser.enqueue(pivot);
        for (int j = 0; j < greater.size(); ++j) {
            lesser.enqueue(greater.dequeue());
        }
        return lesser;
    }

    protected Queue quickSortAge(Queue<Person> queue) throws Exception {
        if (queue.size() <= 1) {
            return queue;
        }
        Queue lesser = new Queue();
        Queue greater = new Queue();
        int pivot = queue.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (compareAge(queue.get(i), queue.get(pivot)) < 0){
                lesser.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
            else {
                greater.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
        }

        lesser = quickSortAge(lesser);
        greater = quickSortAge(greater);

        lesser.enqueue(pivot);
        for (int j = 0; j < greater.size(); ++j) {
            lesser.enqueue(greater.dequeue());
        }
        return lesser;
    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static void addPerson(Scanner scnr, Queue<Person> queue) {
    int age = -1;
        System.out.println("Please enter a person's name in this format: " +
                "FirstName LastName Age.");
        String firstName = scnr.next();
        String lastName = scnr.next();
        try {
            age = scnr.nextInt();
            if (age < 1 || age > 130) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid age");
                scnr.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ie) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid age");
            scnr.nextInt();
        }
        try {
            Person newPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName, age);
            queue.enqueue(newPerson);
            System.out.println("The new person was added.");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Whoops something went wrong. Please try again.");
        }
        finally {
            scnr.nextLine();
        }
    }
    private static void sort(Scanner scnr, Queue<Person> queue) throws Exception {
        QuickSort qs = new QuickSort();
        System.out.println("B");
        queue = qs.quickSortLastName(queue);
        System.out.println("Sorted by last name descending:");
        print(queue);
        System.out.println("D");
        queue = qs.quickSortAge(queue);
        System.out.println("Sorted by age descending:");
        print(queue);
    }
    private static void print(Queue<Person> queue){
        System.out.println("E");
        System.out.println(queue.toString());
        System.out.println("M");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Queue queue = new Queue();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean quit = false;
        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter one of the following options: ");
            System.out.println("A: add new person to the queue, P: print the queue, " 
                   + "S: sort the queue, and Q: quit");
            String input = scnr.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            switch(input){
                case "A":
                    addPerson(scnr, queue);
                    break;
                case "S":
                    sort(scnr, queue);
                    break;
                case "P":
                    print(queue);
                    break;
                case "Q":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid option.");
                    break;
            }
        } while (!quit);
      scnr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting would be useful for a Priority Queue.

Comment: Agreed, but we have to use a queue (stupid).

Comment: `pivot` is of type `int`, when you call `lesser.enqueue(pivot)`, in `quickSortAge(...)`. Later in your `sort(...)` method when you assign `queue = qs.quickSortAge(queue)`, `queue` is of type `Queue<Person>` so it throws the exception because an integer is not a person. You should not use raw types when dealing with Java generics. (i.e. when you declare `lesser` and `greater` don't do `Queue lesser = new Queue()` do `Queue<Person> lesser = new Queue<Person>()`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Thanks, that makes sense. I'll try that out. I originally had Queue<Person>.... then I was like "meh, I can simplify this." Apparently not.

Comment: @KillerSheltie I can see what you're saying, but using raw types is basically the same as declaring the `Queue` as `Queue<Object>`, which will significantly complicate things, not to mention if you had declared `lesser` as a `Queue<Person>` then the Java compiler would have complained with a compile time exception and you wouldn't have gotten the somewhat hard-to-spot `ClassCastException` runtime exception.

Comment: @JonnyHenly It's working now. Thank you!

Comment: No, I'm saying you could implement a Priority Queue with a normal queue by keeping it sorted.

Comment: @ScottHunter interesting. I'll have to research that.

Answer (score 1):

Jonny Henly provided the answer and explanation in the comments.

"pivot is of type int, when you call lesser.enqueue(pivot), in quickSortAge(...). Later in your sort(...) method when you assign queue = qs.quickSortAge(queue), queue is of type Queue so it throws the exception because an integer is not a person. You should not use raw types when dealing with Java generics. (i.e. when you declare lesser and greater don't do Queue lesser = new Queue() do Queue lesser = new Queue(). – Jonny Henly"

Here's the resultant working code snippet:

```
protected Queue quickSortLastName(Queue<Person> queue) throws Exception {
        if (queue.size() <= 1) {
            return queue;
        }
        Queue<Person> lesser = new Queue<Person>();
        Queue<Person> greater = new Queue<Person>();
        int pivot = queue.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (compareLastName(queue.get(i), queue.get(pivot)) < 0){
                lesser.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
            else {
                greater.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
        }
        lesser = quickSortLastName(lesser);
        greater = quickSortLastName(greater);

        lesser.enqueue(queue.get(pivot));
        for (int j = 0; j < greater.size(); ++j) {
            lesser.enqueue(greater.dequeue());
        }
        return lesser;
    }

    protected Queue quickSortAge(Queue<Person> queue) throws Exception {
        if (queue.size() <= 1) {
            return queue;
        }
        Queue<Person> lesser = new Queue<Person>();
        Queue<Person> greater = new Queue<Person>();
        int pivot = queue.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (compareAge(queue.get(i), queue.get(pivot)) < 0){
                lesser.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
            else {
                greater.enqueue(queue.get(i));
            }
        }

        lesser = quickSortAge(lesser);
        greater = quickSortAge(greater);

        lesser.enqueue(queue.get(pivot));
        for (int j = 0; j < greater.size(); ++j) {
            lesser.enqueue(greater.dequeue());
        }
        return lesser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.